# Jekyll - Collection - output:true doesn't work

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am very new to Jekyll and really liking it so far. Right now I am stuck at a point. I have a events collection.

If I say output:false the events are rendered by the for loop.

But If I set output: true events are not rendered by the for loop

Events for loop

```
{% for event in site.events %}
<div class="{% cycle 'style1', 'style2' %} row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ event.url }}">{{ event.title }}</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">{{ event.summary }}</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">{{ event.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Config.yml with output false

```
collections:
  events:
    output: false
```

Config.yml with output true

```
collections:
  events:
    output: true
```

From the tutorials, it seems that just by setting output true, it should have worked. I am setting output: true because I want a separate page for each document.

Its working on github pages. But doesn't working fine on local

Here is my repository URL https://github.com/RobinNagpal/Ion-Jekyll-Theme

Comment: Can you add the contents of an item of the collection as an example?

Comment: did you create the collection folder: `_events` in the root directory ? cf [jekyll /docs/collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/)

Comment: That is the reason its working on github pages and as output:false

Comment: A repository url maybe ?

Comment: https://github.com/RobinNagpal/Ion-Jekyll-Theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used a date field in your yaml front matter.

As those dates are in the future, your events are not published (same as posts collection).

In order to have your events published, you can set a `future: true` in your `_config.yml`. This will instruct jekyll to publish (create a file) future events.